# Is it still equivocation when a listener willfully misinterprets a speaker's words?

Tags: logic, fallacies

I know that equivocation is using the same term in an ambiguous way, but does it only count if it all comes from the same person? If so, what would you call this?

> Speaker A: "Please stop. I'm begging you. This is the most dangerous thing you've ever done."
>
> Speaker B: "Nah, remember? I did that lady with the throwing knives strapped to her thighs. Now, *she* was dangerous."

Here, the verb "do" is being used in two senses. In the first line of dialogue, it's being used to mean *to perform an action*, and in the second it's used to mean *to have sex with*. If it's a willful misinterpreation, is it equivocation, or is it some other diversionary tactic? Is there even a term for it?

Comment: The term in this case is humor :).  Knowing the fallacies is most (only?) valuable when you are engaged with someone who is committed to the rules of discourse.  Then you can bring up the fallacies, wherein the person should alter their argument or accede the point.  If you don't have this basic agreement in place, there's no point even arguing.  Further, in the case like the above where the second person is just horsing around or willfully being difficult, then the rules of discourse are out the window.  Argument over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance in your question is not the **fallacy of equivocation**.

It is equivocation on the linguistic level, but it is not the fallacy, because a fallacy is an error in argumentation. Moreover, in the case of informal fallacies, these are generally judgment calls with respect to their applicability (it's generally not an appeal to authority to trust a doctor's diagnosis).

In this case, no argument is being made -- hence no fallacy. To give several equivalents, you can't strike out if you aren't playing baseball/softball. You can't miss your high jump if you're not even in the high jump. You can't has misspoken in French when speaking English.

Now, that's not to say there is not equivocation -- the use of the same words with different meanings in the two sentences, just that this doesn't make it a fallacy.

Comment: Thanks for the clear response! That makes sense. If someone were to make an argument, and a second person's attempt at rebuttal did something like that, would it be equivocation then?

Comment: Yes, that would be an equivocation since  the rebuttal is an argument.